# How to display timeline information for routines used by controllers in glimpse/Asp.NET MVC

Tags: glimpse

I am currently using Asp.Net MVC 4 and I would like to include the time of some routines used by my controllers in the glimpse's timeline tab.

I know that I have to create an ITimeLineMessage Implementation and send the timing information with a message broker. But how to create the ITimeLineMessage ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a way but its not very nice and not supported:

- Retrieve the MessageBroker for the following static method:

  - `Glimpse.Core.Framework.GlimpseConfiguration.GetConfiguredMessageBroker()`
- Then publish an ITimelineMessage to the MessageBroker:

  - `messageBroker.Publish(timelineMessage)`
  - Note, you could create a generic message type that you use over again that implements `ITimelineMessage`
- To populate the properties of your ITimelineMessage implementation you might also need `IExecutionTimer`. You can get this via the following static method:

  - `Glimpse.Core.Framework.GlimpseConfiguration.GetConfiguredTimerStrategy()`
  - The above will have the knowledge of when the request started for offsets etc.

As @nikmd23 said, we know this is about as bad as what you could ever want to do but v2 will see a much much more simple way of doing this.

Comment: Nice guys, for profilling reasons is always nice to have a logger accessible globally. Static methods/accessor  on this case is not bad.

Answer (score 4):

Here is an implementation using anthonyv's suggestion:

https://gist.github.com/droyad/8292852

Answer (score 0):

You can create any custom class you want, that class just has to implement `ITimelineMessage`.

As a general heads up, [we are currently working through a way to make this WAY easier](https://github.com/Glimpse/Glimpse/pull/302). If the approach described there interests you, please do provide your feedback.

Comment: Ok, but how to get the MessageBroker. I also need a timer  and how to

Comment: get the time where the request started ?