# Can I add events in my Code that appears in the Glimpse Timeline?

Tags: glimpse

I am trying to debug multiple DB connections, which the Glimpse Timeline shows, but I am not sure what they relate to. Can I add code, like Trace, that will appear in the Glimpse Timeline tab.

Thanks

EDIT

Found it:

[Custom Events for Glimpse Timeline](http://getglimpse.com/Docs/Timeline-Tab)

Not quite.... Only for V2 which is not released yet...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work for what you want - [How to display timeline information for routines used by controllers in glimpse/Asp.NET MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18721058/how-to-display-timeline-information-for-routines-used-by-controllers-in-glimpse). There is also this - http://thenextdoorgeek.com/post/Extending-Glimpse-for-ASPNET-to-include-custom-Timeline-messages.

Comment: thank you for this. Most useful. Any idea when v2 will be out, which I understand will include this functionality? Fabulous utility, by the way. Huge thanks.